# Adding NSMutableArray to TableView in Second Tab from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have had no issues following the following tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1. In essence, this tutorial teaches one to create a simple table view populated with data from a NSMutableArray and the subsequent drilling down into the DetailView of each item.

I then tried to enhance what I had by creating a TabViewController and having the created Table View as the 'Tab item 2' of this controller.

This has broken the auto-population of the Table.

The code used to populate the tables from **AppDelegate.m**

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    Person *person1 = [[Person  alloc] initWithName:@"Monica"
                                            balance:420
                                         thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"01.jpg"]
                                          fullImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"01_t.jpg"]];
    Person *person2 = [[Person  alloc] initWithName:@"Ross"
                                            balance:630
                                         thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"02.jpg"]
                                          fullImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"02_t.jpg"]];
    Person *person3 = [[Person  alloc] initWithName:@"Rachel"
                                            balance:420
                                         thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"03.jpg"]
                                          fullImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"03_t.jpg"]];

    NSMutableArray *persons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:person1, person2, person3, nil];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initialViewController = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;
    TableViewController * peopleTableViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PersonTableViewController"];
    [peopleTableViewController setPersons: persons];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

'persons' is an array of Person instances which is a property of TableViewController. The following is the population of the table based on the 'persons' array from **TableViewController.m**:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PersonCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    //For each person
    Person *person = [self.persons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = person.name;
        cell.imageView.image = person.thumbImage;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [person getPrice];

    return cell;
}
```

Lastly, the storyboard is located here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9axs8.png

And just to re-iterate, this all compiles fine but during tests, the table is empty upon opening tab item #2 (where the table view controller exists as per the storyboard). This was working before I added the tabs.

I am still very new to Objective C, so please let me know if there is any other information you may require.

Comment: Note that 'persons' is NULL on TableViewController [viewDidLoad] but it is correctly set when I check at the bottom of appDelegate [didFinishLaunchingWithOptions]

Comment: Not sure about this, since I don't usually use `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` but maybe the `-viewDidLoad` of the tableViewController is getting called before you set the `persons` ivar on the controller (i.e. in `-instantiate...`) This would explain the `NULL`. You could try doing `[tableView reloadData]` in `-viewWillAppear:` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are instantiating new view controllers rather that using the ones that are already in the storyboard. When this app starts up, the tab bar controller, as well as its content view controllers will all be instantiated. Also, because one of the controllers, the one in tab 2, is a navigation controller, its root view controller, TableViewController will also be instantiated. So, you just need to get a reference to this table view controller, not create a new one:

```
    UITabBarController *tabVC = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *nav = tabVC.viewControllers[1];
    TableViewController *peopleTableViewController = nav.topViewController;
    [peopleTableViewController setPersons:persons];
```

This should work, but I think it would be better to move the creation of the Person objects and the persons array to the viewDidLoad method of the table view controller.

Comment: Thanks very much! It works now! I am very new to Objective C and haven't mucked around with pointers since 3-4 years ago doing C for a bit so it is a bit overwhelming trying to figure out whether I'm pointing to addresses or creating new instances!

The main change it seems was the .viewControllers[1] - I was thinking of going down this path but wasn't sure if it broke best-practices by directly referencing item #1 in the array. Thanks for confirmign!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
 Person *person = [self.persons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Try put your code in `ViewDidLoad` instead of `AppDelegate`and run it. (just for test it)

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes I agree that I am breaking best-practices by getting AppDelegate to create the array. I will be making sure I keep any similar elements in the correct classes. With a background in C, Java & PHP, I am still learning this complex language. If you do know of any material that covers best practices, it would be very handy!

Comment: While on this topic, is it general practice to create a custom class for every View Controller created? I tried googling and checked SO pretty thoroughly but a concise Yes or No doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: I have a good book about it:
`iPhone App Developement - Build an App in 5 days with ios 6 SDK by Nick Kuh`

and yes, I think it's a genereal pratice to create a class for each view controller, but sometimes it depends what you'll do on it. Check the book that I told you.